# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 V6 connection time out and command timeout not working

Tags: c#, db2, connection-string, oledb, connection-timeout

I am using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 V6 provider to connect to db2 database in my .NET 4.5.2 application using C# and this is my connection string:

```
Provider=DB2OLEDB.1;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Initial Catalog=DSNP;Data Source=DSNP;Network Address=10.0.202.145;Network Port=666;Default Schema=PPBANCS;Connect Timeout=10;
```

As you see I have set `Connect Timeout` to `10` seconds but the problem is notwithstanding I can see this value inside the `OleDbConnection.ConnectionTimeout` property but it does not work and `OleDbConnection.open()` waits for connection for ever. Also have this problem too with `OleDbCommand.CommandTimeout`.

```
  private void Connect()
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
         connection.Open();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.